# SUPER Simple TimePicker Implementation - Force Closes on Line 74

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timepicker, android-sdk-tools

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point... im trying to vew data stored by the time picker - but every time I run the application I get force close errors.

P.S.

It appears the issue is stemming from Line 74 in View Country.java

timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex));

DATA OUT - JAVA:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 
   private TimePicker timeTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
         int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("time", timeTv.getCurrentHour());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}
```

DATA OUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="1" 
  android:layout_margin="5dp">

   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/nameText" 
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/capText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="Time Limit"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/codeText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="Linked Users"/>         
     <TextView 

        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/code_lbl"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>  

  </TableRow>
```

DATA INPUT - JAVA

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private TimePicker timeEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
      timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);


      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));  
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(),
            timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
            codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

DATA INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:padding="5dp">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/name_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

  <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10MB" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Unlimited Data" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10kbs" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:hint="@string/code_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




  <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

## ViewCountry.java Updated w 1st Suggestion Source Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 
   private TimePicker timeTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
         int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("time", timeTv.getCurrentHour());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}
```

## view_country.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<TableRow>         
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/nameText" 
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/capText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

  <TableRow>       
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>                    
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/codeText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Linked Users"/>         
 <TextView 

    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

MOST RECENT LOGCAT: (after adding  timeEdit to a TextView in view_country.xml)

```
03-22 03:02:27.724: D/Activity(32616): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 03:02:27.794: W/dalvikvm(32616): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410889d8)
 03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.nfc.linkingmanager/com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry}:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to  android.widget.TimePicker
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.TimePicker
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.setUpViews(ViewCountry.java:38)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.onCreate(ViewCountry.java:30)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4701)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
03-22 03:02:27.794: E/AndroidRuntime(32616):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: where is line number 74 in ViewCountry.java?

Comment: timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex));

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? Try debugging. Just place a breakpoint somewhere in onPostExecute() (such as line 74) and inspect the state of result, timeIndex and timeTv. You'll be able to tell very quickly which one of those objects are null.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
```

instead of

```
timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
```

because you have defined TimePicker id  `android:id="@+id/timeEdit"` but trying to get `timePicker1` which is not available in current Activity layout or make sure you are using right layout for Activity

Comment: I tried it (still crashing on line 74 at -  timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex)); still? - judging from the updated logcat [posted above in bold])

Comment: @NoobNinja : also post your add_country xml file

Comment: @NoobNinja : make sure u have added timeEdit timePicker in view_country.xml ?

Comment: I added it (I posted it above - it's still crashing - can you check to insure I implemented it as you thought it should be done?)

Comment: Does - <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>

- seem correct to you?

Comment: @NoobNinja : no change this to :`<TableRow> <TextView style="@style/StyleLabel" android:text="Time Limit"/> <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timeEdit" style="@style/StyleText"/> </TimePicker>`

Comment: Ok - I tried changing <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>

to

<TableRow> <TextView style="@style/StyleLabel" android:text="Time Limit"/> <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timeEdit" style="@style/StyleText"/> </TimePicker>

and now I'm getting an error stating Mismatched tag.